# SQL - delete record from table X if same record not in table Y

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

sorry to make a big fuss about delete same records again, but i can't find any solution :(

i need something like that:
if a select of 3 columns values from table1
is **NOT** equal to the same select in table2
than delete record from table2
that are my aproaches:

```
DELETE FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
ON table2.basketid = table1.basketid AND
table2.artid = table1.artid
WHERE table1.userid='007'

DELETE FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT basketid, artid
FROM table1
)
AND userid ='007'
```

Thanks for your help or any tipp!!

Comment: is this a sql server question?

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in SQL Server

```
DELETE  t2
FROM    Table2 t2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   Table1 t1
                     WHERE  t1.basketid = t2.basketid
                            AND t1.artid = t2.artid )
        AND t2.userid = '007'
```

notice the filters in the select that compares the values in Table2 to Table1

if userid is also in Table2 you might want to add that to the WHERE also

```
DELETE  t2
FROM    Table2 t2
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   Table1 t1
                     WHERE  t1.userid = t2.userid
                            AND t1.basketid = t2.basketid
                            AND t1.artid = t2.artid )
        AND t2.userid = '007'
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need a where (  ) not in (  )

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE (basketid, artid ) NOT IN (
       SELECT basketid, artid
       FROM table1
      )
AND userid ='007';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE y
FROM  X
LEFT JOIN Y
ON 
    X.COL1=Y.COL1
AND
    X.COL2=Y.COL2
AND
    X.COL3=Y.COL3
WHERE 
    Y.COL1 IS NULL
```

Try the above code.